# objects of knowledge

Tags: meaning-in-context

What are "objects of knowledge" here? I know it is talking about the school of thought that believes one can not distinguish between objects and our perception of them, but why "objects of knowledge"? what is the difference between "objects" and "objects of knowledge"? DOes it mean "the objects that we have knowledge about" which simply implies "objects"?

On the one side is the school of neo-realism, which posits that objects and phenomena exist in themselves and can be studied rationally and empirically, independent of one’s mental state.5 There is an immaculate universe ‘out there’. On the other side is the phenomenalist contention that one cannot distinguish between **objects of knowledge** and objects as one perceives them. Linguistic philosophy examines how basic epistemological words such as ‘knowledge’ and ‘perception’ are used.

(Art and Science by Sian Ede)

Answer (score 1):

You're in the wrong forum.  Your questions cannot be answered by understanding English usage.  Yours are questions of philosophy and may be addressed [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/).

I'm going to try to justify the above, and I'm sorry it's in an answer, but a comment's length restrictions preclude using one.

"Objects of knowledge" is a term of art and must be treated as a unit.  Forgive the oversimplification, but in Plato's philosophy, there's a world of Being and a world of Becoming.  The former contains his famous forms -- eternal and unchanging.  Think of a mathematical triangle -- three sides of zero width, three angles adding to exactly 180°.  The latter is world we perceive, in which things are transient and ever-changing.  Think of triangles in drawings and buildings.  These triangles come and go as their drawn, torn up, built, and razed.  Their sides have thickness and their angles are approximate.

The things in the world of Being are objects of knowledge; those in the world of Becoming are objects of opinion or perception.  The former are always true, and the latter are only sometimes true.

Comment: thank you so much for your explanation. It was so useful :)